# Spring Batch Integration Test - Job parameters are not accessible at run time

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-batch

I implemented a test using JobLauncherTestUtils passing parameters. But in my JobParametersValidator
I verify that there are no past parameters. What may be the problem ?

```
@Component
public class ParameterValidator implements JobParametersValidator {

    @Override
    public void validate(JobParameters parameters) throws JobParametersInvalidException {


        String param = parameters.getString("param");

        . . . 
        //param not exists here
        if (!StringUtils.hasText(param)) {
            throw new JobParametersInvalidException("Param Error");
        }
        . . . 
    }   
}   

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@SpringBatchTest
public class IntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;  

    @Test
    public void test() {


        JobParametersBuilder paramsBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
        paramsBuilder.addString("param", "1");

        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep(
                "stepName", paramsBuilder.toJobParameters());

    }


}
```

Comment: Are you sure your parameter validator is called? Because when you use the `jobLauncherTestUtils` to launch a step, a `SimpleJob` is created around the step and it does not set any job parameter validator: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/d8fc58338d3b059b67b5f777adc132d2564d7402/spring-batch-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/test/StepRunner.java#L135-L137.

Comment: Yes, the validator is certainly called. Because he throws the exception throw new JobParametersInvalidException("Param Error").

Comment: in this case, please provide a minimal example that reproduces the issue to be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.